# Enable Stripe in Sylius

Tags: symfony, stripe-payments, sylius, payum

I have an install of Sylius which I'm trying to get hooked up to Stripe for payments. I did some reading, and found out that Stripe is included within Payum. Okay, off to install Payum.

So I followed the first part of the instructions here: https://github.com/Payum/Stripe/blob/master/Resources/docs/checkout.md

```
php composer.phar require payum/stripe php-http/guzzle6-adapter
```

After that, it seemed that Sylius and Symfony went their separate ways with configs, because everything I've read about Payum on sylius references the standard config.yml file, rather than the config.php file which is referenced in the Payum documentation. So I found the basic configuration online elsewhere instead, and added this to my config.yml:

```
payum:
    security:
        token_storage:
            myBundle\CoreBundle\Entity\PayumSecurityToken:
                doctrine:
                    driver: orm
    contexts:
        stripe:
            omnipay:
                type: Stripe
                options:
                    apiKey:  my_key_is_here
                    testMode: true
                actions:
                      - sylius.payum.stripe.action.capture_order_using_credit_card
                      - sylius.payum.action.obtain_credit_card
                      - sylius.payum.action.order_status
                      - sylius.payum.action.execute_same_request_with_payment_details
            storages:
                myBundle\CoreBundle\Entity\Order:
                      doctrine:
                          driver: orm
                Sylius\Bundle\PaymentsBundle\Model\Payment:
                      doctrine:
                          driver: orm

sylius_payments:
     driver: doctrine/orm
     gateways:
            stripe: Stripe
```

With these changes, I now receive the error:

> There is no extension able to load the configuration for
>   "sylius_payments" (in /Users/Me/Code/mysite/app/config/config.yml).
>   Looked for namespace "sylius_payments", found "sylius_installer",
>   "sylius_order", "sylius_money", "sylius_currency", "sylius_contact",
>   "sylius_locale", "sylius_settings", "sylius_cart", "sylius_product",
>   "sylius_archetype", "sylius_channel", "sylius_variation",
>   "sylius_attribute", "sylius_taxation", "sylius_shipping",
>   "sylius_payment", "sylius_mailer", "sylius_report",
>   "sylius_promotion", "sylius_addressing", "sylius_inventory",
>   "sylius_taxonomy", "sylius_flow", "sylius_pricing", "sylius_sequence",
>   "sylius_content", "sylius_search", "sylius_rbac", "sylius_user",
>   "sylius_ui", "sylius_admin", "sylius_shop", "sylius_metadata",
>   "sylius_association", "sylius_review", "sylius_core", "sylius_web",
>   "sylius_resource", "sylius_grid", "winzou_state_machine",
>   "sylius_api", "sonata_block", "cmf_core", "cmf_block", "cmf_content",
>   "cmf_routing", "cmf_menu", "cmf_create", "cmf_media", "doctrine",
>   "doctrine_cache", "doctrine_phpcr", "assetic", "framework", "monolog",
>   "security", "swiftmailer", "twig", "sonata_intl", "bazinga_hateoas",
>   "fos_oauth_server", "fos_rest", "fos_elastica", "knp_gaufrette",
>   "knp_menu", "knp_snappy", "liip_imagine", "payum", "jms_serializer",
>   "jms_translation", "stof_doctrine_extensions",
>   "white_october_pagerfanta", "doctrine_migrations", "sylius_fixtures",
>   "sylius_payum", "sylius_theme", "debug", "web_profiler" in
>   /Users/Me/Code/mysite/app/config/config.yml (which is being imported
>   from "/Users/Me/Code/mysite/app/config/config_dev.yml").

I'm not sure where to go from here, as there is very little documentation to be found on the subject.

Comment: maybe this `sylius_payments` is wrong, instead could be `sylius_payment`

Comment: Indeed, this did start throwing a different error now. Good catch! Now it's complaining about: InvalidConfigurationException in ArrayNode.php line 317:
Unrecognized option "contexts" under "payum"

Comment: You installed a a payum's stripe extension but trying to configure ominpay bridge. That's two completely different things. And you are using very old version, do you? Consider upgrade to newer ones, a lot of fixes and new features there.

Comment: The contexts is from very old versions of payum, right now it is called `gateways`.

Comment: I had a little too much going on in that config. With your help and some further hunting online, I've refined it now and have it working:

payum:
    gateways:
        stripe:
            factory: stripe_js
            publishable_key: my_publishable_key
            secret_key: my_secret_key

My only problem now is that everything runs without error, but the payment method still doesn't show up in the admin 'payment method' section. All I see available is 'offline' (currently set) or 'paypal express checkout'. How do I get this to show, now that it's enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to propose a possible answer. Based on help I received from the comments and external resources, I've formulated that my config.yml might simply need the following (after installing via composer of course: php composer.phar require payum/stripe php-http/guzzle6-adapter)

```
payum:
    gateways:
        stripe:
            factory: stripe_checkout
            publishable_key: my_pusblishable_key
            secret_key: my_secret_key
```

This seems to be all it needs to not throw an error upon starting, like the code in my original question did. I've since cleared the cache, and restarted the server. However, I don't see any new options appearing in my 'payment methods' panel in the Sylius admin. Shouldn't this now be showing as a viable option? I won't accept my answer until we figure out what it takes to really get Stripe working.

*edit*

Looks like that other little bit I had, activating the gateway I just defined, was correct. After adding that, everything is now working and the gateway shows up correctly in the admin panel. Huzzah!

```
sylius_payments:
     driver: doctrine/orm
     gateways:
            stripe: Stripe
```

The full solution to getting Stripe working in Sylius is:

Install via composer:

Add this to your config.yml:

```
payum:
    gateways:
        stripe:
            factory: stripe_checkout
            publishable_key: my_publishable_key
            secret_key: my_secret_key

sylius_payment:
     driver: doctrine/orm
     gateways:
            stripe: Stripe
```

Clear the cache:

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

Restart the web server, for good measure. That's it!